# Autupostback on textbox works even though data is not validated

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

This is my asp.net markup:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Style="width: 100px;" ID="txtCon" OnTextChanged="txtCon_TextChanged" MaxLength="10" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationGroup="con" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCon"
                            Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Format. Ex. 12 is valid format" ValidationExpression="(\d){1,10}" />
```

Problem is if I type in abc in textbox and tab out of the control it still does a postback. I want to stop this behavior. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use OnTextChanged event instead use javascript function for eg keyup let me know if this helps

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server"  Style="width: 100px;" ID="txtCon"   MaxLength="10" AutoPostBack="false" /> <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationGroup="con" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCon"
                            Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Format. Ex. 12 is valid format" ValidationExpression="(\d){1,10}" />
```

js function

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("txtCon").each(function () {
                $(this).keyup(function () {
                   //your function here
                });
            });

        });
```

Comment: But I want to postback to server when user tabs out of the textbox but only postback if the data in the textbox is indeed valid.

Comment: use javascript funciton  for validation if validation is true then function should return true else return false . If function will return true then it will go to server side

Answer (score 0):

add **ValidationGroup="con"** AND **CausesValidation="true"** in text box

replace your text box with this

```
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Style="width: 100px;" ID="txtCon" OnTextChanged="txtCon_TextChanged"
    MaxLength="10" AutoPostBack="true" ValidationGroup="con" CausesValidation="true"/>
```